# Can you convert a Google Calendar Event into a Reminder?

Tags: google-calendar

When creating an Event, you can select making a Reminder or Task instead.
(These options are only available when you have the respective calendars `[✔]` enabled to display, under `My calendars`.  In this screenshot, I have `[✔] Reminders` displayed, but not `[ ] Tasks`:
[image]

But when editing an already created Event, I can’t find such a choice anymore:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, unfortunately you cannot** convert a Google Calendar Event into a Reminder.

As for:

> *When creating an Event, you can select making a Reminder instead*

It is not *"instead"*. It is just an option you are given upon creation between creating an `Event` or a `Reminder` or a `Task`

Comment: Thanks.  ((IMHO saying “instead” makes sense, because creating an Event is the default – Reminders  and Tasks are secondary, requiring an extra click. (Plus, they literally go in the same stead. ;) )))

Comment: Thanks for the hint that Tasks are similar in this context to Reminders!  I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: The issue here is that an `Event` carries many more fields with information than either a `Task` or a `Reminder`. Information that would certainly be lost if converted to either of them.

Comment: and yet, @marikamitsos, this is exactly what I want to do, even though some information "would certainly be lost". I feel that Google engineers sometimes have trouble empathizing with ordinary human users.